# External monitors on laptop used to work but not after update

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have 2 monitors connected to my laptop on mini-DP ports. I used to have all the 3 screens including my main laptop display working but not today. I don't know how to start troubleshooting. Any pointers? I have Nvidia GeForce on intel i5.

Edit:
Ubuntu version: 20.04
kernel: 5.4.0-54-generic
NVidia GeForce GTX 1050 mobile

Laptop was updated yesterday through `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you are using and what update? For example, did you update from one version to another or was it from the software updater? A kernel update perhaps?